# Explenation about opcode and operand

Tags: assembly

I need an explanation about the term "opcode". I have found this :

> An opcode is binary or hex value of the machine instruction in the cpu
>   instruction set.

If I understand correctly the definition, for instance :

```
6A 03  push 3
```

6A is the opcode et 03 the operand. But in several posts on different forums, people talk about 03 as if it was an opcode (for instance [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/what-is-an-immediate-value)

> Here, 3 is an immediate because it's included directly as part of the opcode (in the second byte).

).

Does 03 is an opcode **and** an operand?

Comment: An instruction is composed of many parts which are not necessarily byte sized.

Comment: To reduce confusion, it's better to refer `6A 03` as the instruction with opcode and operand being `6A` and `03` respectively. The mnemonic would be `push 3`.

Comment: Compare `0xCC INT 3` – an opcode *and* its operand, in a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this specific push and according to the [Intel SDM](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf) (Page can be identified by searching Vol. 2B 4-507) 03 is both a part of the opcode and the "argument". The full opcode of "`push 03`" is "`6A 03`"

As far as I know Intel SDM consistently uses the term opcode as "all the content of the assembly command, including operands".
  [image: Table of possible PUSH opcodes in the SDM]